# Linked List nodes attribute is updating everytime with recent value

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list, fread

I have written a **C** code which just reads **'n'** number of lines (each line is a string of 7 letters including spaces) where **'n'** is the first line of input from the user. For each input line i'm creating a linked list node with **node->src** as the input line. Successive lines of input are linked together in the linked list.

Everything works fine for me. Expect that the value stored in **node->src** updates everytime to the most recent input line provided by the user. This I could see from the **'prev'** and **'current'** values which I'm printing in the given code. But the pointer values of current and next are proper. I'm not able to locate the problem in my code. Kindly help. I'm running the code in **gcc compiler (Linux Ubuntu 12.04)**

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
  char *src;
  struct node *next;
};


int main(){
    int index,n;
    struct node *Head;
    struct node *currNode;
    Head = NULL;
    struct node *newNode;
    char line[8];
    printf("Enter input\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(index = 0; index < n-1; index++){
        newNode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        fread(line, sizeof(line), 1, stdin);
        newNode->src = line;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        printf("%s\n",line);
        if(Head == NULL){

            Head = newNode;
            currNode = Head;

        }
        else{
            printf("prev %s\n",currNode->src);
            currNode->next = newNode;
            currNode = currNode->next;
            printf(" current %s\n",currNode->src);
        }

    }


    for(newNode = Head; newNode != NULL; newNode=newNode->next){
        printf("%p",newNode);
        printf("%p",newNode->next);
        printf("%s\n",newNode->src);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all the node `src` elements point to `line`.  Hence, when the value of `line` changes, all the node `src` elements also appear to change.

The end result is whatever remain's in `line` is what all the node's will be pointing to.

To fix the problem, each node `src` will need to point to it's own memory:

Change:

```
newNode->src = line;
```

to:

```
newNode->src = strdup(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do malloc not only for your node, but for it's element node->src too. Or use struct

```
struct node {
   char src[8];
   struct node *next;
};
```

instead. And use strcpy() for assigning value to node->src.